# Transforming observer object in VueJS

Tags: javascript, json, object, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to validate the form and usually i do it the way i'm going to put here, problem is that I can't assign object to component object, also it doesn't show it in template if component data changes, should i use watch and how to do it since i learn Vue:

```js
validate(data) {
    Object.entries(data).map(field => {
        if (field[1] == "") {
            errors[field[0]] = "Can't be blank";
        } else if ( data.password !== "" &&
            field[0] == "confirm_password" &&
            field[1] !== data.password {
            errors[field[0]] = "Passwords don't match";
        }
    });
    return errors;
 },
 signUp(data) {
     this.errors = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.validate(data)));
     console.log(this.errors);
     if (Object.keys(this.errors).length == 0) {
         this.register(data);
     }
 }
```

'data' is object inside the data of the component...

I tried to transform it this way `JSON.parse((JSON.stringify(object))`, tried also `Object.assign({}, this.validate(data))`, `{...this.validate(data)}`

Comment: this code snippet is inside what? could you provide the component template and script?

Comment: This is in component

Comment: this's not sufficient to figure out your problem, please provide more code

Comment: Solved it, thank you anyway :)